# Collision in python Turtle Snake game

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm writing a code where there is a maze that a turtle has to get through. The only issue is that I can't figure out how to create collision with all of the walls. I have been incapable of finding a way of creating barriers without making limits for every coordinate of the wall. I only have access to the turtle and random modules. Is there a way to do this? Here is my code:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
tr=turtle.Turtle()
screen.tracer(0)

mazeWidth=150
tr = turtle.Turtle()
tr.width(5)
tr.speed(0)
tr.penup()
tr.goto(-mazeWidth,190)
def drawMazeSection(color):
  tr.pencolor("lightblue")
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-20,200)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(20,200)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-20,-200)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(20,-200)
  tr.penup()
  tr.pencolor("black")
  tr.goto(-200,200)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-200,-160)
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(-180,-160)
  tr.goto(-180,-200)
  tr.goto(-200,-200)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.goto(-20,-200)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(20,-200)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(200,-200)
  tr.goto(200,200)
  tr.goto(20,200)
  tr.goto(20,140)
  tr.goto(80,140)
  tr.goto(80,180)
  tr.goto(180,180)
  tr.goto(180,-80)
  tr.goto(100,-80)
  tr.goto(100,-140)
  tr.goto(20,-140)
  tr.goto(20,-200)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(20,160)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(-80,160)
  tr.goto(-80,140)
  tr.goto(-60,140)
  tr.goto(-60,160)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.goto(-60,120)
  tr.goto(-20,120)
  tr.goto(-20,100)
  tr.goto(40,100)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(120,140)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(140,140)
  tr.goto(140,100)
  tr.goto(120,100)
  tr.goto(120,120)
  tr.goto(120,140)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.goto(140,100)
  tr.goto(80,100)
  tr.goto(80,80)
  tr.goto(80,60)
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(140,60)
  tr.goto(140,20)
  tr.goto(100,20)
  tr.goto(100,60)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.goto(20,60)
  tr.goto(20,-100)
  tr.goto(20,-40)
  tr.goto(-20,-40)
  tr.goto(-20,-100)
  tr.goto(-60,-100)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-60,-140)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-60,-160)
  tr.goto(-140,-160)
  tr.goto(-140,-120)
  tr.goto(-160,-120)
  tr.goto(-160,-40)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-60,-60)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-60,0)
  tr.goto(-20,0)
  tr.goto(-20,40)
  tr.goto(-60,40)
  tr.goto(-60,80)
  tr.goto(-120,80)
  tr.goto(-120,200)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-160,160)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-160,40)
  tr.goto(-40,40)
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(60,20)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(60,-80)
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(60,-40)
  tr.goto(140,-40)
  tr.goto(140,-20)
  tr.goto(60,-20)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-200,0)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-100,0)
  tr.begin_fill()
  tr.goto(-100,-120)
  tr.goto(-100,-80)
  tr.goto(-120,-80)
  tr.goto(-120,0)
  tr.end_fill()
  tr.penup()
  tr.goto(-20,-140)
  tr.pendown()
  tr.goto(-20,-200)
  
for color in ["#FF0000","#0000FF","#00FF00"]:
  drawMazeSection(color)
  

screen.tracer(1)    
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('darkgreen')

tr.color('red')
tr.penup()

tr.speed(40)
speed = 1.5

wn.mainloop()
tr.penup()
tr.goto(20,-180)
tr.pendown()
tr.shape('turtle')
tr.color("#DB148E")
tr.width(5)
tr.left(90)

tr.penup()
tr.goto(0,-200)
def travel():
    tr.forward(speed)
    wn.ontimer(travel, 10)

wn.onkey(lambda: tr.setheading(90), 'w')
wn.onkey(lambda: tr.setheading(180), 'a')
wn.onkey(lambda: tr.setheading(0), 'd')
wn.onkey(lambda: tr.setheading(270), 's')

wn.listen()
travel()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you need the turtle.window_width() and turtle.window_height functions

### Gets the width and height of a  program

```
width, height = turtle.window_width(), turtle.window_height()

## Gets the boundaries for the x coordinates 
minX, maxX = -width/2, width/2

## Sets the boundaries for the y coordinates
minY, maxY = -height/2, height / 2

## Checks if the turtle hits the boundaries
def check():
    if tr.xcor() <= maxX:
       tr.setheading(0)
    if tr.xcor() >= minX:
       tr.setheading(180)
    if tr.ycor() >= minY:
       tr.setheading(270)
    if tr.ycor() <= maxY:
       tr.setheading(90)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? OP wants to "create collision with all of the walls", like the inner maze walls, not just the edge of the screen.